# Multiplying two matrixes in C

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to multiply two matrixes in C but the result gives me:

```
\23 23\
\23 23\
```

instead of

```
\23 20\
\55 48\
```

1x1 of the matrix keeps repeating and it seems like the `matResult[i][j]=sum` isn't taking in the sum. The number of rows and columns are defined and there are no scans. I also used a function to calculate the multiplication of the matrix so that I could later use it in the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 2  // m is the number of rows
#define N 2  // n is the number of columns

int i;
int j;
int k;
int sum;

/*
Function to calculate the multiplication of 2 matrixes
*/
int multiMat(int mat1[M][N], int mat2[M][N], int matResult[M][N]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        sum = sum + (mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]);
      }
      matResult[i][j] = sum;
      sum = 0;
    }
  }
  return matResult[i][j];
}
int main(void) {
  int mat1[M][N] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  int mat2[M][N] = {{9, 8}, {7, 6}};

  int matResult[M][N];
  printf("\n\n  RESULT ");
  printf("\n  ===============\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      printf("     %d\t", multiMat(mat1, mat2, matResult));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger and step thru it to trace its flow and variable values? At what point do things first start going wrong?

Comment: You have to initialize `sum` before you use it; also your matrix sizes are wrong (which doesn't create any problems when N = M)

Comment: The result of the multiplication is stored in array `matResult`, but you're not printing its elements.  You are instead printing the *return value* of the function.  You are also performing the multiplication N*M times.  You should perform it only once, then just read out the result from `matResult`.

Comment: It doesn't matter in the example because you have M==N, but matrix for A*B to make sense, if A is M rows, N columns, then B must be N rows and M columns, The result is M by M.  So most of the array dimensions and loop bounds are wrong. There are many other errors. Others have made a good start on those.

Comment: @kikon: `sum` is initialized.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't see it

Comment: @kikon: Defining an object with static lifetime initializes it to zero, unless overridden with an explicit initializer. After using `sum` for one result, the program resets it to zero for the next use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right!  I wasn't aware - they haven't told me that for some reason ...

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you very much for your reply! I have hard time understanding the part about the return array 'code'matResult'code', am I not printing the entirety of the values gathered after the for loops when calling the function in the main?

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for replying, I tried running it through what I think is a debugger but couldn't find the flow and variable values.

Comment: @Gene thank you very much for your reply, I realize that the result is M by M but I have a hard time understanding how that makes the loop bounds wrong, aren't they necessary to keep track of the 4 different values and their position in the matrix in the question above?

Comment: Mercifully, the global variables `i`, `j`, and `k` are unused — but they should therefore be removed.  The global variable `sum` is a catastrophe — an open invitation for incorrect results.  Get rid of your global variables.  Avoid global variables like the plague they are.  They are sometimes necessary, but avoid them whenever possible.  In your code, it is trivial to get rid of them.

Comment: @Gene: you can multiply an M×N matrix by an N×P matrix, and the result is an M×P matrix.  In this code, where M≡N, there isn't much of a problem even though M and N are used confusingly.  In the general case, where the dimensions of the arrays are not all the same, a lot more care is needed.

Comment: Correction to my '[Mercifully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955611/multiplying-two-matrixes-in-c#comment130582809_73955611)' comment: The line `return matResult[i][j];` uses the global variables `i` and `j` — mostly by accident.  They are still initialized to zero, so the function returns the value in the top-left corner of the result matrix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you so much for your response, I understand now why `return matResult[i][j]` doesn't work and I've also gotten rid of the global variables. Although the array `matResult[i][j]` still doesn't seem to store in the different `sum` values when I call in the function from the main. How can the gathered values from `matResult[i][j]` in a function be called from the main if it's stuck in a for loop?

Comment: How did you compute the expected the result ? That may be the cause of your problem as the last element of your matrix can not be 48.

Comment: @Oliver - "*am I not printing the entirety of the values gathered after the for loops when calling the function in the main?*" No, you're not.  That is the main point I'm trying to get across to you.  This ... `return matResult[i][j]` ... returns the value of *one element* of the result matrix, and, unsurprisingly, that's *the same* element on each call to `multiMat()`.  Again, call the function *once*.  As called, it writes its result in `main()`'s local array `matResult`.  Therefore, use your loop nest in `main()` to read out the elements of `matResult`.

Comment: All your problems originate from the use of global variables. Simply drop them and only use local ones. Then create one function for multiplication and another for printing. Neither needs to return anything - the original matrix will get modified since the array passed get adjusted to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks a lot for clearing my question up, I thought that `return matResult[i][j]` would return the entirety of the values in the array and not just one value. With your help and the help of others in the comment chain, I finally got it to work!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure. The OP had 2 dimensions, so I just stuck with this apparent desire so that if they were made unequal, the result would still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my version of your code cleaned up.  I've removed `M` as your matrices are square and your code won't easily adapt to multiplying two non-square matrices (though, as I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955611/multiplying-two-matrixes-in-c?noredirect=1#comment130582875_73955611), you can multiply an M×N matrix by an N×P matrix, and the result is an M×P matrix).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 2  // n is the size of the square matrices

static void multiMat(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int matResult[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + (mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]);
            }
            matResult[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

static void printMat(const char *tag, int mat[N][N])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, N, N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf(" %3d", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int mat1[N][N] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    int mat2[N][N] = {{9, 8}, {7, 6}};
    int mat3[N][N];

    multiMat(mat1, mat2, mat3);

    printMat("Mat1", mat1);
    printMat("Mat2", mat2);
    printMat("Mat3", mat3);

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces the output:

```
Mat1 (2x2):
   1   2
   3   4
Mat2 (2x2):
   9   8
   7   6
Mat3 (2x2):
  23  20
  55  48
```

The result (renamed `Mat3` in this code) is what you wanted.  It's often a good idea to print the inputs as well as the output — it ensures that the computer is thinking about things the same way you are.  It also encourages writing functions like `printMat()`.  It is possible to provide the dimensions of the matrices to the functions using VLA (variable-length array) notation.  For example, a more general matrix multiply function might be:

```
void MatrixMuliply(size_t M, size_t N, size_t P, int mat1[M][N], int mat2[N][P], int mat3[M][P])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < P; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                sum += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            mat3[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your advice, I've taken heed of them all and will apply them in the future! Your version of the code works like a charm, although I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the values from the array `matResult[i][j]` can be printed in the function `printMat` when I don't see a call of the function `void MultiMat` in it.

Comment: The calculation is done by the separate call to `multiMat()` — it assigns the result to the third matrix.  Then the printing code is called to print each of the three matrices (two input matrices, one output matrix).  It's usually a good idea to separate I/O operations from calculations, and I've done that by creating and calling the `printMat()` function to output a matrix.  The calculation function(s) should not do I/O except perhaps for error reporting.